# как сделать из двух массивов один вложенный? php

Tags: php, laravel

сделать нужно из

```
$arr = ['tolik', 'misha', 'egor'];
$arr2 = ['brat', 'swat', 'drug'];

чтобы получилось 
$arr3 = [
          ['name' =>'tolik', 'RELATIONSHIP' =>'brat'], 
          ['name' =>'misha', 'RELATIONSHIP' =>'swat'],
          ['name' =>'egor', 'RELATIONSHIP' =>'drug']
        ];
```

Comment: любые операции над массивами проводятся с помощью цикла

Comment: кстати, я не знаю, это специально или нет, но brat - это хулиган, swat - спецназ, а drug - лекарство.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$arr3 = [];

foreach ($arr as $key => $name) {
     $arr3[] = ['name' => $name, 'RELATIONSHIP' => $arr2[$key]];
}
```